# Why can i reference docker services in nginx config?

Tags: docker, nginx

I deployed an app using docker and it has some magic in it.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  restapi:
    build: ...
  frontend:
    build: *nginx_image*
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream kitschoen_rest {
    server restapi:8000;
}
```

I am maveling why it is possible to reference a docker service in my nginx config. I have read about docker container networks and about nginx upstream servers ... but I still haven't a clue. Can someone shed some light on this? How does nginx connect to my docker services?

Comment: That becomes their internal domain name from docker's perspective.

Answer (score 1):

If a container is given a name, the embeded DNS server that Docker has will create a DNS entry where the given container name points to the container's IP.  Consider the Docker docs [Embedded DNS server](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#embedded-dns-server):

> Docker daemon runs an embedded DNS server which provides DNS
>   resolution among containers connected to the same user-defined
>   network, so that these containers can resolve container names to IP
>   addresses. If the embedded DNS server is unable to resolve the
>   request, it will be forwarded to any external DNS servers configured
>   for the container. To facilitate this when the container is created,
>   only the embedded DNS server reachable at 127.0.0.11 will be listed in
>   the container’s resolv.conf file. For more information on embedded DNS
>   server on user-defined networks, see embedded DNS server in
>   user-defined networks

You are giving your services names, so nginx can just refer to them as though they were "real" domains.

Comment: thanks ... I did not know about the DNS server ... so I did not really know what to look for.